# c++ classes , this works but can someone make it better so it meets standards/coding practices

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 




class Calculator
{
        public: 
          int number1; 
          int number2 ; 

        public: 

        void  setCalcNumbers(int input1 , int input2 )
          {

          number1 = input1; 
          number2 = input2; 
          }
          int addNumber()
          {
              return number1 + number2;
          }
          int subtractNumber()
          {
              return number1 - number2;
          }
          int divideNumber()
          {
              return number1 / number2;
          }
          int multiplyNumber()
          {
              return number1 * number2;
          }

};

int main()
{
    int numberInput1 = 0; 
    cout << "Enter number 1: "; 
    cin >> numberInput1; 


    int numberInput2 = 0;
    cout << "Enter number 2: "; 
    cin >> numberInput2;

    Calculator t; 
    t.setCalcNumbers(numberInput1, numberInput2);

    char userOperationChoice; 
    cout << "which operation would you like to perform? "
         << " , enter M for Multiplication, D for Division, A for addition or S for Subtraction:" << endl;

    cin >> userOperationChoice; 
    char a,d,m,s;
    switch (userOperationChoice) 
    {

    case 'a'  : 
         t.addNumber();
         cout << "the total is: " << t.addNumber() << endl; 
         break; 

    case 's':
         t.subtractNumber(); 
         cout << "the total is: " << t.subtractNumber() << endl; 
         break ; 
    case 'd': 
         t.divideNumber();
         cout << "the total is: " << t.divideNumber() << endl; 
         break; 
    case 'm':
         t.multiplyNumber();
         cout << "the total is: " << t.multiplyNumber() << endl; 
         break; 

    }        



    system("pause"); 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: But keep in mind that you are in no way obligated to disclose whether this is homework or not.

Comment: @Andreas: I think that goes without saying. But if you tag it appropriately, you'll get better answers. Feel free to omit relevant information, or even tag it as `[sql]` or `[python]` too, if you like. But you'll get the most helpful answers if you tag it as what it *is*. And that is true for homework as well. Tagging it as such doesn't mean we won't answer, just that we put more emphasis on helping the OP understand the issue, rather than simply providing ready-to-use code.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is homework, so I will give the extra short version.
Particularly, I would go down the [function template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(programming)#Function_templates) path.

```
template <typename T> T  add(T n1,T n2){                                        
        return n1 + n2; 
}
```

and use it:

```
 int s = add<int> (1,3);
```

Considering that you ask about classes , I would eliminate the setNumbers function, and make every function static, and receiving as parameters the numbers to operate on. Additionaly, I would make it a [template class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(programming)#Class_templates).

Why types are important ? Well, right now your calculator can only operate on integer numbers. So what happens if the user inputs floating point numbers, such as `1.5` and `3.2` ? As you are using `int` types, the chosen operation will be between the numbers `1` and `3`, as they are truncated. Not so bad? Well, consider this case. The user inputs numbers `3` and `0.5`, and chooses to divide. What will happen ? Yes, the black hole generator: division by zero. So, the `template class / function` is the appropiate way. If you are only looking for an integer calculator, I'd suggest renaming the class to `integerCalculator` and doing some validation on the user input (for avoiding fatal errors such as dividing by zero more gracefully).

For example

The template class

```
 template <typename T> calculator {
      static T add (T n1 ,T n2){
        return n1 + n2;
      }
    };
```

The integer calculator

```
class integerCalculator{
  public:
          //other functions

          int divideNumber(){
                 if (number2 == 0) //handle error
                 return number1/number2;
          }
};
```

Some more on your version:

`number1` and `number2` should not be public, or if the are, why do you need a `setNumber()` function? Reduce their visibility (`private` seems apropiate).

```
class Calculator{
        int n1;
        int n2;

   public:  void setNumbers(int n1,int n2){...}
   //add, divide, multiply, subtract functions
}
```

Seems that the `a`,`d`,`m`,`s` variables are unused. If they are not part of the solution...

Comment: I think you mean "number1 and number2 should _not_ be public"

Comment: What's the purpose of making the function static ? It doesn't bring anything to the table and they certainly not need any access to the private parts of `calculator` (which doesn't even have any in your proposal), the free standing methods are much better.

Comment: @Matthieu M. Let me answer with another question: What state should a calculator that performs only operations mantain ? Thats the reasoning behind the static proposal.

Comment: @Tom: I agree that there is no state. And thus if there is no state, there certainly isn't any need for a class... since classes are meant to encapsulate state. The `static` collection of methods grouped within a class come from Java/C# and their lack of free function support, in C++ they are a non-sense... and an objective proof would be that they cannot be picked up by ADL.

Comment: @Matthieu M. Yes, I agree. My first option would be function templates, no doubt. But as the op. is asking for classes, I gave that one. I agree it should not be a C++ solution though.

Answer (score 0):

1. define your variables top of Main function;
2. try to setting " default " section for " switch " statement;

have fun ...

Comment: there is no point in defining the variables at the top of main, it's an antiquated habit from c programmers which has nothing to do in C++ and is adverse to the idea that variables should have the tighter scope possible for clarity purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. make all those functions `const` i.e. `int multiplyNumber () const;`
2. You could consider operator overloading because that's a bit more intuitive in many situations.
3. It's probably a typo, but you should only have 1 `public:` section. The data members should be `private`.
4. Create a constructor with initializers:

   `Calculator (const int n1, const int n2) : number1(n1), number2 (n2) { }`
5. Besides function templates as in another answer already, standard practice would be to make this a class template to accept any data type, not just int.

   `template <typename T> class Calculator { /* ... */ }`

Thus you could declare `number1` and `number2` as type `T`.

Comment: the low side of #4 is that Calculator would only operate on n1 and n2.

Comment: @Tom: I was assuming that the content of the calculator should stay the same and the answer was supposed to help with making the definitions a bit more `standard`. The initializers would cut out a bit of code for setting the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a,d,m,s;
```

before the Switch statement ? Why do you have them/need them there ?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be a bit rash, but please understand it's for your good ;)

The class `Calculator` is useless. It serves no purpose here. A class is meant to encapsulate a state and control the access to this state so that it can maintain a number of invariants.

For example, if you think of a dynamic array with the following members:

```
size_t mNumberItems; // number of items in the array
size_t mCapacity;    // maximum number of items in the array
T* mElements;        // array
```

The following invariants hold:

- `mNumberItems` <= `mCapacity`
- `mNumberItems` represents the number of items in the array, it's always in sync
- `mCapacity` reprents the maximum capacity of the array, it's also in sync

So I would consider rewriting the code as:

```
int getNumber(char const* text)
{ 
  int number = 0;
  std::cout << text << std::endl;
  std::cin >> number;
  return number;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int n1 = getNumber("Please enter the first number:");
  int n2 = getNumber("Please enter the second number:");

  char userOperationChoice; 
  cout << "which operation would you like to perform?\n"
       << "Enter * for Multiplication, / for Division, "
       << "+ for addition or - for Subtraction:" << endl;

  cin >> userOperationChoice;

  int total = 0;
  switch(userOperationChoice)
  {
  case '*': total = n1 * n2; break;
  case '/': total = n1 / n2; break;
  case '+': total = n1 + n2; break;
  case '-': total = n1 - n2; break;
  default:
    std::cout << userOperationChoice
              << " is not in the set of operators allowed" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  std::cout << "Total is: " << total << std::endl;
}
```

It's not perfect (lack of input validation on the numbers), but I have factorized much.